# Вернуться к вам с ответом

Tags: лексика

Является ли корректной фраза с точки зрения русского языка?

> Из-за большого количества обращений мы сможем вернуться к вам с
> ответом лишь в течение двух дней.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

*Грамматически* такое предложение возможно, но воспринимается оно странным образом: если обещают *вернуться с ответом*, это означает, что ***уходят решать этот вопрос** и это займёт столько-то времени*, однако объяснение задержки опирается на ***занятость другими** обращениями* и потому выглядит нелогично (корректные сами по себе выражения противоречат одно другому). Правильнее было бы сказать, что (по названной причине) "*вынуждены **отложить** решение вашего вопроса на срок до двух дней*".